# execute python file from php error

Tags: php, python, django, shell

I have some problem.

this php (uploads.php) script execute  gif.py python file.

```
<?php


    $file_path = "uploads/";
    $auth_token = $_POST['auth_token'];
    mysql_connect('localhost',"login",'pass');
    mysql_set_charset("UTF-8");
    mysql_select_db("DB_name");

    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE auth_token='$auth_token'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_fetch_array($result)['user_id']==0)
    {
        echo "fail auth_token ".$auth_token;
        exit;
    }

    $file_md5 = md5(time()+$auth_token+rand(0,1000));

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$file_md5.".mp4")) {
        $aaa = exec("/usr/bin/python gif.py b9022c5c317cf2317ad3f537dcc1cfbe");
        echo $file_md5."   ".$aaa;
    } else{
        echo "fail ".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']." ".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']." ".$file_path ;
    }
 ?>
```

**gif.py file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from moviepy.editor import *
import sys

file_md5 = sys.argv[1]

anna_olaf = (VideoFileClip("uploads/" + file_md5+".mp4")
     .subclip(0,1)
         .resize(1))  

anna_olaf.write_gif('gifs/test.gif', fps=15)
```

I have in uploads folder `b9022c5c317cf2317ad3f537dcc1cfbe.mp4` file. Where i call gif.py or uploads.php file from the Linux console all ok(php uploads.php OR pyhon gif.py), but where I call uploads.php  from browser python file don't work, in apache log i find

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py:296: UserWarning: IPython parent '/var/www' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  " using a temp directory."%parent)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gif.py", line 2, in <module>
    from moviepy.editor import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy-0.2.1.8.12-py2.7.egg/moviepy/editor.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .video.io.sliders import sliders
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy-0.2.1.8.12-py2.7.egg/moviepy/video/io/sliders.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 774, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 692, in rc_params
    fname = matplotlib_fname()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 604, in matplotlib_fname
    fname = os.path.join(get_configdir(), 'matplotlibrc')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 253, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 478, in _get_configdir
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to create %s/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data"%h)
RuntimeError: Failed to create /var/www/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data
```

Please help, in log write error in 2 line ( from moviepy.editor import * ) but why I not have error where call ( python gif.py )?

Comment: The error is not shown in the last line of your error report:
`RuntimeError: Failed to create /var/www/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data`

I would say it's probably a permissions problem with the `/var/www/` folder not allowing the script to create the file as needed.

Comment: ooooo yeeeeeeeeeeeees !!! thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you for help. :)

Comment: I'll post the comment as an answer just in case anyone else runs into similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the problem is shown in the last line of your error report, see:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create /var/www/.matplotlib; consider setting MPLCONFIGDIR to a writable directory for matplotlib configuration data
```

I would say it's probably a permissions problem with the `/var/www/` folder not allowing the script to create the file as needed.

To fix that you should change the permissions on the folder to make it writable or specify a different directory to which the script should create the needed file.